# neo4j server not starting up

Tags: ubuntu, azure, neo4j

I had a neo4j server running on an AzureVM. There was a recent maintenance on Azure post which my server has stopped from starting up again. The log gives the following error:

```
*2014-08-10 00:26:49.405+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
Detected incorrectly shut down database, performing recovery..
2014-08-10 00:26:58.298+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully started database
2014-08-10 00:27:02.451+0000 INFO  [API] Starting HTTP on port :7474 with 10 threads available
2014-08-10 00:27:03.435+0000 INFO  [API] Enabling HTTPS on port :7473
2014-08-10 00:27:05.086+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted discovery module at [/]
2014-08-10 00:27:05.109+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted REST API at [/db/data/]
2014-08-10 00:27:05.120+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted management API at [/db/manage/]
2014-08-10 00:27:05.156+0000 DEBUG [API]
org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j Server failed: org.neo4j.server.configuration.Configurator.getThirdpartyJaxRsPackages()Ljava/util/List;
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:218) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.server.configuration.Configurator.getThirdpartyJaxRsPackages()Ljava/util/List;
        at org.neo4j.server.extension.auth.AuthenticationExtensionInitializer.getMyMountpoint(AuthenticationExtensionInitializer.java:101) ~[authentication-extension-2.0.3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.neo4j.server.extension.auth.AuthenticationExtensionInitializer.start(AuthenticationExtensionInitializer.java:82) ~[authentication-extension-2.0.3-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.3-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.neo4j.server.modules.ExtensionInitializer.initializePackages(ExtensionInitializer.java:60) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.server.modules.ThirdPartyJAXRSModule.start(ThirdPartyJAXRSModule.java:61) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.startModules(AbstractNeoServer.java:310) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:183) ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
        ... 2 common frames omitted
2014-08-10 00:27:05.157+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7474]*
```

It seems that the server is unable to find getThirdpartyJaxRsPackages(). Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Edit: The neo4j version is 2.0.1 community distribution

Comment: Hi, there. Were you able to figure out how to solve this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have a version conflict, you use the authentication-extension for version 2.0.3
But the Neo4j server is version 2.0.1

So best is to upgrade your server to 2.0.3 too.

As I assume you don't want to build a custom build for the auth-extension for 2.0.1 ?

Comment: Hi, Michael. How do you do a custom build for 2.0.1? Running into the same issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.